# Как изменить триггер для рисования в Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leafletjs

Всем доброго времени суток!

Для проекта используются карты `Leaflet`. Т.к. клиентская часть - React-приложение, то используется пакет `react-leaflet`. Для рисования на карте используется `leaflet-draw`. Все вроде бы хорошо и ровно, за исключением того, что при рисовании любого элемента, для упрощения возьмем `polyline`, новый vertex добавляется при нажатии любой кнопки мыши на карте. Т.е. если мне нужно побегать по карте в режиме рисования, то каждое мое перетягивание вызовет появление нового vertex (вершины) для моего объекта.

Анализ сорсов `leaflet-draw` показал, что они рисуют новую вершину по событию `touchstart`. Можно ли как-то переопределить это поведение?

Answer (score 0):

После долгих поисков натолкнулся на решение своей проблемы [вот тут](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/935#issuecomment-577151194).

Если говорить именно о моем случае, то мне требовалось пофиксить данную проблему для типов `Polygon` и `Polyline`. Согласно варианту, предложенному в ссылке следовало сделать так:

Для полигона
`L.Draw.Polygon.prototype._onTouch = L.Util.falseFn;`

Для полилинии
`L.Draw.Polyline.prototype._onTouch = L.Util.falseFn;`

Однако, в этом случае собрать приложение не удастся из-за ошибки "Property '_onTouch' does not exist on type 'Polygon'/ 'Polyline'", хотя при проходе под дебагом эти методы вполне себе видны. И в качестве решения данной проблемы был создан метод `changeBehavior(lDraw:any)`, на вход которому подается объект `L.Draw`, а в теле выполняются операции, описанные выше.